# Spring Boot React in separate packages

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-boot, jhipster

I have a spring boot, java 8 API that I wanted to add a React front end to to make API operations easier to navigate and use. I used [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) generator to generate a React app. Then I just took the web portion and dropped into my app, however whenever I run the Spring Boot application and try to navigate to port `:8080` it, I get the following page:

[image]

And the following error in the console:

```
2019-07-15 15:07:21.414  INFO 29145 --- [)-10.15.114.229] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]                                            : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-15 15:07:21.414  INFO 29145 --- [)-10.15.114.229] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                                    : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-15 15:07:21.414 DEBUG 29145 --- [)-10.15.114.229] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                                    : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2019-07-15 15:07:21.426 DEBUG 29145 --- [)-10.15.114.229] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                                    : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2019-07-15 15:07:21.426  INFO 29145 --- [)-10.15.114.229] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                                    : Completed initialization in 12 ms
2019-07-15 15:07:25.079 DEBUG 29145 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                                    : GET "/", parameters={}
2019-07-15 15:07:25.093 DEBUG 29145 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.d.s.w.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping          : looking up handler for path: /
2019-07-15 15:07:25.128 DEBUG 29145 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping                            : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2019-07-15 15:07:25.130 DEBUG 29145 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler                         : Resource not found
2019-07-15 15:07:25.131 DEBUG 29145 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                                    : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2019-07-15 15:07:25.152 DEBUG 29145 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                                    : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2019-07-15 15:07:25.153 DEBUG 29145 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.d.s.w.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping          : looking up handler for path: /error
2019-07-15 15:07:25.167 DEBUG 29145 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping                   : Mapped to public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2019-07-15 15:07:25.199 DEBUG 29145 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver                     : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2019-07-15 15:07:25.208 DEBUG 29145 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                                    : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Here is my project structure:

```
FooApplication
├── build.gradle
├── api/
    ├── src.main.java.com.foo/
            ├── FooApplication.java
    └── build.gradle
├── web/
    ├── node_modules/
    ├── src.main.webapp/
        ├── app/
            ├── index.tsx
            ├── routes.tsx
            └── app.tsx
        └── index.html
    ├── webpack/
        └── webpack.common.js
    └── build.gradle
```

Here my `webpack.common.js` file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const {BaseHrefWebpackPlugin} = require('base-href-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

const utils = require('./utils.js');

const getTsLoaderRule = env => {
  const rules = [
    {
      loader: 'cache-loader',
      options: {
        cacheDirectory: path.resolve('build/cache-loader')
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'thread-loader',
      options: {
        // There should be 1 cpu for the fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin.
        // The value may need to be adjusted (e.g. to 1) in some CI environments,
        // as cpus() may report more cores than what are available to the build.
        workers: require('os').cpus().length - 1
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: {
        transpileOnly: true,
        happyPackMode: true
      }
    }
  ];
  if (env === 'development') {
    rules.unshift({
      loader: 'react-hot-loader/webpack'
    });
  }
  return rules;
};

module.exports = options => ({
  cache: options.env !== 'production',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'
    ],
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    alias: {
      app: utils.root('src/main/webapp/app/')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: getTsLoaderRule(options.env),
        include: [utils.root('./src/main/webapp/app')],
        exclude: [utils.root('node_modules')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          digest: 'hex',
          hash: 'sha512',
          name: 'content/[hash].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        loader: 'tslint-loader',
        exclude: [utils.root('node_modules')]
      }
    ]
  },
  stats: {
    children: false
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: `'${options.env}'`,
        VERSION: `'${utils.parseVersion()}'`,
        DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: options.env === 'development',
        // The root URL for API calls, ending with a '/' - for example: `"https://www.jhipster.tech:8081/myservice/"`.
        // If this URL is left empty (""), then it will be relative to the current context.
        // If you use an API server, in `prod` mode, you will need to enable CORS
        // (see the `jhipster.cors` common JHipster property in the `application-*.yml` configurations)
        SERVER_API_URL: `''`
      }
    }),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({tslint: true}),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/css', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/css'},
      {from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/lib', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/lib'},
      {from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.min.js', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.min.js'},
      {from: './src/main/webapp//swagger-ui/', to: 'swagger-ui'},
      {from: './src/main/webapp/static/', to: 'content'},
      {from: './src/main/webapp/favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico'},
      {from: './src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp', to: 'manifest.webapp'},
      // jhipster-needle-add-assets-to-webpack - JHipster will add/remove third-party resources in this array
      {from: './src/main/webapp/robots.txt', to: 'robots.txt'}
    ]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/main/webapp/index.html',
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
      inject: 'body'
    }),
    new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({baseHref: '/'}),
  ]
});
```

How do I get spring boot to serve up the `index.html` file when navigating to `localhost:8080`? I know I'm going to have to override some default spring boot configurations to get this to work but I'm not clear on what configurations.

I can provide details of any more files upon request, just didn't want to overload the post with unnecessary info.

Comment: Have you ran mvn clean install after you moved your packages?

Comment: this is a gradle project but yes I've done gradle clean build

Comment: I suppose you created the React part following our doc about separating server and client https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/#directory-layout. Generate server part in a separate folder using `--skip-client`and copy relevant parts of config package (Webconfigurer, SecurityConfiguration, etc) to your own backend  with related application properties. But maybe it would be easier to copy parts of your api into a working backend generated by JHipster.

Answer (score 0):

Request mapping for your application's entry point, read the file, and return the content. In my case, the React code is stored at /tmp/build/index.html. Simplified and ignoring errors, it might look something like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getIndexContent() {
        final File file = new File("/tmp/build/index.html");
        final String content =
                FileUtils.readFileToString(
                        file,
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .body(content);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring-boot auto-configures some paths by default as static resource locations: `/static`,  `/public` or `/resources`. See the [Official Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

So if you can move your index.html and dependent assets into the static resource paths, Spring Boot should serve them as-is.
Alternatively, as those same docs say, you could add new paths as a static locations by setting the `spring.resources.static-locations` property.

A nice thing to do would be to build your React application, bundling the resources, and copying the bundled assets + index.html to the Spring project's static location.

You haven't mentioned anything about your build setup, if you're using the Gradle Node Plugin with Webpack, then this shouldn't be hard. This [blog post](https://andrew-flower.com/blog/Spring-Boot-and-React-1) shows how you'd do that (however, not using multiple modules)